# Responsive images using img vs background

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've been working on adding an animated hover effect and have worked out a solution using img and background image which can be viewed [here](http://jkeohan.github.io/#/tpl2).  I like the background image better but just read that using img is better for screen readers and search engines as per this [article](https://thedotproduct.org/when-to-use-an-img-tag-when-to-use-a-css-background-image/).

The issue I'm having is that when testing responsiveness the img solution looks warped when compressed to col-xs-6 while the background solution doesn't.  The img css is using:

```
.hovereffect img {
  width: 150%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Now I've tried using `height:auto` but then the pic doesn't fill the full height, which is something I want to do. Is there anyway to maintain the img proportions when it scales down?

Comment: Please include here enough code to reproduce your issue ... and if possible ellaborate a working example so we can edit your code

Comment: You are dealing with a classic front end dilemma. You lose alt tags with background images, but lose nice scaling with img tags. I reckon you put semantic text on top of a bg image and if you don't want to show that simply move that text off the screen with absolute positioning. Use something like an h3 if the text is important enough to warrant inclusion in the document seo structure.

Comment: The first question is does the image add any context or content to the page? if not then background images are fine and will have no accessibility impact as they will be ignored. If they do (e.g. containing text within the image or add other context somehow) then yes, image tags would be preferred

Comment: So I figured out the solution, although it's not responsive...It involved removing the width set on the img tag and setting on it's parent: width:100%, overflow:hidden.   This way, although the image bleeds out of it's parent (which overflow cuts off) it still maintains it's original proportions.